# CUDAQ[] returns false in Mathematica 10.0.2.0, Mac OS 10.13.2, CUDA Driver Version 387.99

Tags: cudalink, gpu

[image]

`CUDAQ[]` returns False on my Mac OS 10.13.2.
I typed `` Needs["CUDALink`"] `` and it returns no error.

`CUDAResourceInformation[]` gives me the information of my system. But `CUDAInformation[]` does not.

`CUDAQ[]` returns `False`.

I tried `CUDAResourcesUninstall` and `CUDAResourcesInstall`. But it does not help. Anybody have a solution.

Comment: Does your graphics card support CUDA at all?  Apple hasn't used NVIDIA cards since 2014.  If yes, does CUDA work on your computer at all (have you tried other programs)?  Since upgrading to 10.13, I haven't been able to get CUDA working. It keeps giving me an ["update required"](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6chLi.png) message.

Answer (score 1):

(For posterity,) the "Update Required" is because High Sierra is (probably) using the Apple NVIDIA driver. You need to install

1. NVIDIA's web drivers
2. their CUDA driver
3. the correct CUDA libraries for your "updates version" of Mac OS.

Finally as always with NVIDIA drivers, the version you use has to be compatible with the version of the software you are trying to pair with: for example - Xcode 10.1 will work ok with CUDA 10 drivers but not CUDA 8 drivers. The same is probably true of Mathematica.